# Why is Photoshop changing my CMYK numbers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, cmyk, color-conversion

I have my image mode set to CMYK. But as soon as I enter 0 C, 0 M, 0 Y, 50% K, it changes it 43% C, 35% M, 35% Y, 1% K. Attached is a screenshot.

How do I remedy this?

[image: Color picker with incorrect values]

Comment: i only get that when i select the CMYK colors in the swatches. If i make my own color using K + adding it to swatches, it doesn't convert it. 
As to why, i'd say that it works maybe as it converts black to rich black, so it'd do the same to "lighter" versions of a K color... ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have "Only Web Colors" selected. Turn that off as its essentially irrelevant on modern computers. It's trying to figure out how to best represent 50% K in a vastly reduced RGB palette known as [Web Safe Colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Web-safe_colors).

Comment: That did the trick. Looking around I saw that option in the lower left corner of my color picker panel. I wonder how that option got turned on.